# Who is calling delete?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I stack with this error:

> CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught
>   from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to
>   -controllerDidChangeContent:.  attempt to delete row 0 from section 0, but there are only 0 sections before the update with userInfo (null)

I have no idea who calls delete operation — honestly speaking I just don't have any deletes in the entire project. Any ideas how to debug such cases?

```
public func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
    switch(type) {
    case .insert:
        self.operation.append(BlockOperation(block: {
                                                        self.tableView?.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath!], with: .bottom)
                                                    })
        )
        // self.tableView?.scrollToRow(at: newIndexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
        break
    case .update:
        self.operation.append(BlockOperation(block: {
                                                        self.tableView?.reloadRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .bottom)
                                                    })
        )
        break
    default:
        break
    }
}

public func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    self.tableView?.beginUpdates()
    for o in self.operation {
        o.start()
    }
    self.tableView?.endUpdates()

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Update 1

```
override public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: ChannelTableCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ChannelTableCell", for: indexPath) as! ChannelTableCell
    cell.setChannel(self.channelController.object(at: indexPath), delegate: self)

    return cell
}
```

Update 2

I have simplified didChange method and now get error right on reloadRows() call.

```
public func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
    switch(type) {
    case .insert:
        self.tableView?.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath!], with: .bottom)
        break;
    case .update:
        self.tableView?.reloadRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .bottom)
        break
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Stack

```
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109db2d4b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001089cb21e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109db6e42 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010856066d -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 195
    4   UIKit                               0x000000010ab1ab60 -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] + 6265
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010ab34f62 -[UITableView _updateRowsAtIndexPaths:updateAction:withRowAnimation:] + 331
    6   Joker                               0x00000001080335ac _TFC5Joker17AirViewController10controllerfTGCSo26NSFetchedResultsControllerPSo20NSFetchRequestResult__9didChangeP_2atGSqV10Foundation9IndexPath_3forOSC26NSFetchedResultsChangeType12newIndexPathGSqS4___T_ + 860
    7   Joker                               0x0000000108033740 _TToFC5Joker17AirViewController10controllerfTGCSo26NSFetchedResultsControllerPSo20NSFetchRequestResult__9didChangeP_2atGSqV10Foundation9IndexPath_3forOSC26NSFetchedResultsChangeType12newIndexPathGSqS4___T_ + 256
    8   CoreData                            0x0000000109a25400 __82-[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _core_managedObjectContextDidChange:]_block_invoke + 6608
    9   CoreData                            0x00000001098fa9a7 developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 199
    10  CoreData                            0x00000001098fa85f -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 255
    11  CoreData                            0x0000000109a23a17 -[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _core_managedObjectContextDidChange:] + 119
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109d505ec __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109d504eb _CFXRegistrationPost + 427
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109d50252 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 50
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109d13282 -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 2018
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109d1231b _CFXNotificationPost + 667
    17  Foundation                          0x000000010849181b -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66
    18  CoreData                            0x00000001098e2d90 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalNotificationHandling) _postObjectsDidChangeNotificationWithUserInfo:] + 704
    19  CoreData                            0x0000000109979a91 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _createAndPostChangeNotification:deletions:updates:refreshes:deferrals:wasMerge:] + 1713
    20  CoreData                            0x00000001098dcb32 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _processRecentChanges:] + 3554
    21  CoreData                            0x00000001098b5764 -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] + 420
    22  libswiftCoreData.dylib              0x000000010c769e78 _TFE8CoreDataCSo22NSManagedObjectContext5fetchuRxSo20NSFetchRequestResultrfzGCSo14NSFetchRequestx_GSax_ + 56
    ...
)
```

Comment: Not related: What is the benefit of using block operations in a table view?

Comment: Its not related to CoreData its related to TableView with wrong insert row or null insert row please post cellForRow method for more info.

Comment: Hm, @vadian, why not? This is how I used to implement auto update. Any good?

Comment: It's overkill. It can be useful only for a collection view but not for a table view. Have a look how Apple implements the delegate methods. And `break` is not needed in Swift. The cases don't fall through by default.

Comment: @CodeChanger have posted. I put a breakpoint there — no one called

Comment: @vadian will try to simplify. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The immediate cause of your problem is that you are using `indexPath` for row update when you should use `newIndexPath`.

The reason is that `indexPath` is the index *before* any inserts or delete and `newIndexPath` is the index *after* the inserts and deletes.

If you want to update a tableView or collectionView from a fetchedResultsController and have it *never* crash this is how you do it:
Have 5 mutable objects - rowInsert, rowDelete, rowUpdate, sectionInsert, sectionDelete. The rowInsert, rowDelete and rowUpdate are mutable arrays of indexPaths (ie `NSMutableArray<NSIndexPath*>*`). The sectionInsert and sectionDelete are mutable index sets (ie `NSMutableIndexSet*`). In `controllerWillChangeContent` clear the arrays.  On each change add the appropriate indexPath. For insert and update use `newIndexPath`, for delete use `indexPath`, for move add `newIndexPath` to rowInsert and `indexPath` to rowDelete.  In `controllerDidChangeContent` sort rowInsert and sectionInsert ascending and sort sectionDelete and rowDelete descending.  (You can leave rowUpdate in whatever order it is in.) Now apply the changes in the following order: rowDelete, sectionDelete, sectionInsert, rowInsert, rowUpdate.